# How efficient are BlockingQueues / what's their effect on CPU time?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, blockingqueue, linkedblockingqueue

I am making an online game in Java and I ran into one particular issue where I was trying to find the most efficient way to send clients spawn entity NPC packets. I of course understand how to send them but I wanted to do it off of the main game loop since it requires looping through a map of NPC's (I also made sure its thread safe). To do this I thought a BlockingQueue was my best option so I created a new thread set it to daemon then passed in a runnable object. Then whenever I needed to send one of these packets I would use the insertElement() method to add to the queue. Here is how it looks.

```
public class NpcAsyncRunnable implements Runnable {
  private final BlockingQueue<NpcObject> blockingQueue;

  public NpcAsyncRunnable() {
      blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
      while(true) {
          try {
              final NpcObject obj = blockingQueue.take();
              //Run my algorithm here
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

      }
  }

  public void insertElement(final NpcObject obj) {
      blockingQueue.add(obj);
  }
}
```

Now my question is how efficient is this? I am running the thread the whole time in an infinite loop because I always want it to be checking for another inserted element. However, my concern is if I have too many async threads listening would it start to clog up the CPU? I ask this because I know a CPU core can only run 1 thread of execution at a time but with hyperthreading (AMD has the same thing but its called something different) it can jump between executing multiple threads when one needs to search for something in memory. But does this infinite loop without making it sleep mean it will always be checking if the queue has a new entry? My worry is I will make a CPU core waste all its resources infinitely looping over this one thread waiting for another insertion.

Does the CPU instead auto assign small breaks to allow other threads to execute or do I need to include sleep statements so that this thread is not using way more resources than is required? How much CPU time will this use just idling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...does this infinite loop without making it sleep mean...?

`blockingQueue.take()` *does* sleep until there's something in the queue to be taken. The [Javadoc for the `take` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()) says, "Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, *waiting if necessary* until an element becomes available."

"Waiting" means it sleeps. Any time you are forced to write `catch (InterruptedException...)`, it's because you called something that sleeps.

---

> how does it know when something is added if its sleeping? It has to be running in order to check if something has been added to the queue right?

No. It doesn't need to run. It doesn't need to "check." A BlockingQueue effectively* uses [`object.wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) to make a thread "sleep," and it uses [`object.notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) to wake it up again. When one thread in a Java program calls `o.wait()` for any `Object o`, the `wait()` call will not return** until some other thread calls `o.notify()` for the same `Object o`.

`wait()` and `notify()` are thin wrappers for operating system-specific calls that do approximately the same thing. All the magic happens in the OS. In a nutshell;

- The OS suspends the thread that calls `o.wait()`, and it adds the thread's [saved execution context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) to a queue associated with the object `o`.
- When some other thread calls `o.notify()`, the OS takes the saved execution context at the head of the queue (if there is one***), and moves it to the "ready-to-run" queue.
- Some time later, the [OS scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#SCHEDULER) will find the saved thread context at the head of the "ready-to-run" queue, and it will restore the context on one of the system's CPUs.
- At that point, the `o.wait()` call will return, and the thread that waited can then proceed to deal with whatever it was waiting for (e.g., an `NpcAsyncRunnable` object in your case.)

---

* I don't know whether any particular class that `implements BlockingQueue` *actually* uses `object.wait()` and `object.notify()`, but even if they don't use those methods, then they almost certainly use the same operating system calls that underlie `wait()` and `notify()`.

** Almost true, but there's something called "spurious wakeup." Correctly using `o.wait()` and `o.notify()` is tricky. I strongly recommend that you [work through the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) if you want to try it yourself.

*** `o.notify()` does absolutely nothing at all if no other thread is already waiting at the moment when it is called. Beginners who don't understand this often ask, "Why did `wait()` never return?" It didn't return because the thread that `wait()`ed was too late. Again, I urge you to work through the tutorial if you want to learn how to avoid that particular bug.

Comment: Alright thank you that makes sense but how does it know when something is added if its sleeping? It has to be running in order to check if something has been added to the queue right? If so how much does this checking use of CPU time relative to an infinite loop (disregarding the memory concerns)?

Comment: @IDontWantToMakeAnotherAccount, See my updated answer, above.